# Has DC published any non-New 52 comics since the reboot?

Tags: dc, the-new-52

In September 2011, DC Comics rebooted (almost) their entire line of main continuity comics.  They called this event *The New 52*, as there were 52 ongoing titles rolled out as part of the event.  I'll admit to only mildly following DC's comics in the wake of this, but my understanding was that every mainline book (i.e. not their kids line, not Vertigo, etc.) was ended and rebooted as part of this.  [Wikipedia mentions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_52#Publication_history) there was one exception to this, *Batman Incorporated* published one last book [in October 2011](http://www.comicvine.com/batman-incorporated/4050-36705/) and then had a new volume begin that was a New 52 title.

Besides that one exception, have all the main DC comics been New 52 books since then?

Comment: @DVK What is "Too Localized"?  You'll see it's gone from the close reasons.

Comment: thus I didn't VTC. But that still makes it not a very good SE fit despite being an interesting question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### No. And unless there is a drastic change in policy, their previous universe has ceased to exist. (See Teen Titans Go! below for the last exception). Everything published by DC Comics since their "soft reboot" of the DC Universe wears the mark of the New 52 Universe.

There have been [two dozen new books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_52#Publication_history) that have been released since the first new universe offerings. Great efforts are made to bring new characters into the new 52 parallel Earths which now comprise the DCU multiverse. The one exception "Batman, Incorporated" has been since cancelled.

> - At Los Angeles 2011 Comic-Con in June 2011, Dan DiDio, Jim Lee, Bob Harras, Eddie Berganza and Grant Morrison stated after the events of Flashpoint, the DC Multiverse has been restructured yet again as part of The New 52. For example, the main DC Earth formerly known as Earth-0 aka New Earth, the Wildstorm Universe (Earth-50) and Vertigo (its parallel Earth-13) have all been merged into the new primary reality referred to as Prime-Earth.
> - In May 2012, the series [Earth 2](http://www.dccomics.com/tags/earth-2-0) and [Worlds' Finest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worlds%27_Finest) premiered. The first will chronicle the events of a completely reimagined second Earth with the rise of young heroes commonly associated with Earth-2, such as the Flash (Jay Garrick), Green Lantern (Alan Scott), and Atom (Al Pratt). The second title follows the adventures of the Earth-2 Robin and Supergirl, who are stuck on the primary Earth and have since taken up the new costume identities of Huntress and Power Girl, respectively.
> - The same month, Action Comics 9 featured a story about the [Superman of Earth-23](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kalel_%28Earth-23%29). Other Earths in the DC Multiverse have yet to be revealed or explored.

Since this is a "soft reboot" much of the history of the DCU has remained the same, except where the new universe alters previous existing canon. Just a couple of examples:

- Earth 2, for example is now once again the home of Jay Garrick (once called the Golden Age Flash) with a new origin as an avatar of Hermes. He has been returned to around 25-30 years of age.
- On Earth 2, Batman, Superman and Wonder Woman have been killed battling against the invasion of Darkseid's minions of the Fourth World. The stories of Earth-2 now revolve about how the younger heroes continue the fight without the iconic trinity of heroes to lead them.

[image]

DC does not want to have any outstanding works which reference the previous DCU which is one of the reasons theorized by many to have lead to the death of the popular cartoon series [Young Justice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Justice_%28TV_series%29).

- As it stands now, the only lasting active testament to the previous DCU is the television series [Teen Titan's Go!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Titans_Go!_%28TV_series%29) which shows the previous DCU Teen Titans, their villains and their "T" shaped Tower.

> - Teen Titans Go! is an American animated television series based on the DC Comics fictional superhero team, the Teen Titans. The series was announced following the popularity of DC Nation's New Teen Titans shorts, both of which are based on the 2003 Teen Titans TV series.
> - Teen Titans Go! is a more comedic take on the DC Comics franchise, dealing with situations that happen outside of saving the world.
> - Sporting a new animation style, Teen Titans Go! serves as a comedic spin-off with little continuity to the previous series, and only certain elements are retained. Many DC characters make cameo appearances and are referenced in the background, and the show also consists of much darker humor than its predecessor.

Comment: So does that mean the as yet released "Beware the Batman" will be in line with the New 52?

Comment: Its continuity has been kept intentionally vague and seems to  be angling for a Batman Year One kind of feel. Since it's Batman and Gotham centered, the rumor mill has it, the show may eventually try and field the Outsiders (who currently don't seem to exist in the New 52 universe). I don't expect to see anything that will contradict in a major way. It may also be revealed later that this Batman lives on one of the Earths that has not been assigned as of yet in the same way the Young Justice heroes have been assigned to [Earth-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Justice_(TV_series)).

Comment: How does Rebirth fit into this?

Comment: Rebirth is a complete reboot of the DC Universe. The New52 Universe is considered to be over (even if there is no apparent change to how a book looks or acts).

Answer (score 2):

There are several comics launched since then that do not carry the New 52 Logo.  First off is nearly all of the digital/web comics (Batman beyond, Superman beyond, JL beyond, Injustice, etc).  These are most likely excluded since they are not a classic printed comic.

Then comes a few of the comics that are not 'DC world' comics such as He-Man (printed under DC not Vertigo, etc).  There's also Young Justice, which does not seem to be part of New 52 either.

More recently, Batman Black & White, does not seem to be either.  So there is a small percent of comics DC is working on that are not new 52, but most of those are digital.

Can you think of anymore like this Thaddeus?

Comment: smallville seaseon 11

Comment: Legends of the Dark Knight is implicitly old DCU. Pretty much anything not specifically New52 is old DC actually.

Answer (score 0):

The digital series, Legends of the Dark Knight and Superman Adventures frequently involve Non-52 characters and stories.